What's the best way or approach to debug binary Linux library?
I've got a header file (I know the functions and have some documentation) and a .so file:
From a wrapper library and from context, I need to call "Connect", but it does not work, just fails with some obscure error code.
So now my question is: What's the best, easiest approach or tool to find out what this method is doing inside? Given that I know the function, its parameters and such, in Java or C#, I would look at the method's bytecode or MSIL code, ... but I guess the source, which I don't have any access to, was C/C++ (.h).

The standard method to decompile and reverse engineer a binary executable is to use a tool such as Ghidra or IDA (very popular tools for this task). These can help you find the function and decompile the code to C-like pseudo-code.

https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra
https://hex-rays.com/ida-pro/


Use static analysis with radare2. You could also connect with gdb and set break points in either or both programs.
